# Intepreting p values from R mediate() output

Tags: r, mediation

In the output below, the ACME p value shows that it is significant. But the p-value for Prop. Mediated Average  is >10%. I thought Prop. Mediate is the proportion of the total effect mediated by the mediating variable(cong_mesg). So I am confused why ACME is significant but not Prop. Mediated (even for control and treatment groups).Does this show evidence in support of mediation?

[image: mediation ouput]

Comment: This problem is a recurring question (with the same example) that has been treated elsewhere : [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502643/mediation-how-can-the-total-indirect-effect-be-significant-when-the-indirect-ef/506135#506135) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367092/mediation-paths-significant-yet-no-mediation/455526#455526).