# Mediation paths significant, yet no mediation

Tags: spss, mediation

I am using Process by Hayes to run mediation in SPSS. I am using model 4 and have added five covariates.
The results show that the pathways are significant a (p .0211), b (p .0159), c (.0395). Yet, the results for indirect effects of X on Y show that zero is included (BootLLCI -.0065; BootULCI .1309). Considering that all paths are significant, I expected the mediation to work. Am I missing anything from the results output that needs to be considered?
Happy to share more detailed output if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything (in your interpretation), but only power to detect the indirect effect. We can see from the confidence interval that you are barely missing the significance threshold.
This looks like the same problem found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402725/testing-for-mediation).