# Testing for mediation

Tags: mediation

Is it possible for mediation to have occurred via establishing the four steps specified by Baron and Kenny, yet for the Bootstrapping method to indicate no significant mediation effect occurred?

Answer (score 1):

The Baron and Kenny approach is outdated and no longer considered the standard for establishing mediation. Only the significance of the indirect effect is sufficient for establishing the presence of mediation (in ideal conditions of no confounding, correct functional form, etc.). The lack of a significant mediation effect doesn't mean mediation is not occurring; you may just not have enough power to detect it in your sample (e.g., due to small sample size or poorly measured variables).