# Mediation: How can the Total Indirect Effect be significant when the Indirect Effects are not?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

I ran a mediation analysis with two mediators (M1 and M2) using lavaan and I am somehow confused about the results:

---

**Direct Effect:** The total direct effect of X on Y is not significant. X is, however, significantly related to M1 and M1 is significantly related to Y. As for M2, no significant direct relationships are observed.

**Indirect Effect:** The indirect effect of X on Y through M1 is not significant. The same also applies to M2.

**Total Indirect Effect:** When adding the two indirect effects, a significant result is shown. How is that possible?

**Total Effect:** The total effect is not significant.

---

I am mostly confused about the **Total Indirect Effect**. How can it be significant when the two indirect effects are not?

It might be useful to add that I let M1 and M2 covary. Could this serve as an explanation?

Comment: "I let M1 and M2 covary. Could this serve as an explanation?" No.

Comment: The total indirect effect is a bit like a multivariate test, where the individual effects are univariate tests. They should not be expected to agree. You picked a threshold (presumably 0.05). Pick a different threshold and this won't be true.

Answer (score 1):

The total indirect effect is actually the sum of all specific indirect effects, or, more simply the total effect between $X$ and $Y$ less the direct effect between $X$ and $Y$. You can obtain barely significant specific indirect effects (which I guess happened) and when you add them up, it can reach the significance threshold.

Comment: Are you aware of any references that explain this further?

Comment: @canderson156 A place to start : https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol18-1/p066/